# Euler differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have following three equations $$ u'' - 2u = -2v$$ $$ u(0)=0 $$ $$ u'(1)=0 $$
and from these 3 equations I am trying to find u(v).

It looks to me "Cauchy-Euler Differential Equations - Nonhomogeneous case" but I am not sure about that because it is not an exactly Cauchy form. Could you help me to figure out u(v)?

thanks in advance

Comment: Find C.F then P.I. use the conditions to find the value of the constants.

Comment: Do you know the "Method of Undetermined Coefficients"? It can be applied to determine the solution to the inhomogeneous problem.

Comment: I am not familiar about the "Method of Undetermined Coefficients" or the CF & PI. This is the first differential equation at this type which I encounter it in my research as an engineer. But getting familiar now about those. But if you give me couple main steps about these, it would be really helpful. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the homogeneous case is

$u_c(v)=c_{1}e^{\sqrt{2}v}+c_{2}e^{-\sqrt{2}v}$ and by inspection, we observe that a particular solution is $u_p(v)=v$ so the solution to the general case is

$u(v)=c_{1}e^{\sqrt{2}v}+c_{2}e^{-\sqrt{2}v}+v$. Then,

$u(0)=0\Rightarrow c_1+c_2=0$

$u'(1)=0\Rightarrow \sqrt{2}c_{1}e^{\sqrt{2}}-\sqrt{2}c_{2}e^{-\sqrt{2}}+1=0$

from which

$c_1=\dfrac{-1}{\sqrt{2}e^{\sqrt{2}}+\sqrt{2}e^{-\sqrt{2}}}\ $

and

$c_2=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}e^{\sqrt{2}}+\sqrt{2}e^{-\sqrt{2}}}$

Now $u(v)=u_c(v)+u_p(v)$

Comment: I have learned that the answer should be $$ u(v)= v - \frac{Sinh \sqrt{2}v}  {\sqrt{2} cosh \sqrt{2}} $$ But I need to figure out steps to get this result because I would use similar derivation in my project. I would really appreciate any comments or helps. Thanks